# Different EOF behavior with read versus ignore

Tags: c++, iostream

I was recently just tripped up by a subtle distinction between the behavior of `std::istream::read` versus `std::istream::ignore`.  Basically, `read` extracts N bytes from the input stream, and stores them in a buffer.  The `ignore` function extracts N bytes from the input stream, but simply discards them rather than storing them in a buffer.  So, my understanding was that `read` and `ignore` are basically the same in every way, except for the fact that `read` saves the extracted bytes whereas `ignore` just discards them.

But there is another subtle difference between `read` and `ignore` which managed to trip me up.  If you read to the end of a stream, the EOF condition is not triggered.  You have to read *past* the end of a stream in order for the EOF condition to be triggered.  But with ignore it is different: you only need to read to the *end* of a stream.

Consider:

```
#include <sstream>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    {
        std::stringstream ss;
        ss << "abcd";
        char buf[1024];
        ss.read(buf, 4);
        std::cout << "EOF: " << std::boolalpha << ss.eof() << std::endl;
    }

    {
        std::stringstream ss;
        ss << "abcd";
        ss.ignore(4);
        std::cout << "EOF: " << std::boolalpha << ss.eof() << std::endl;
    }
}
```

On GCC 4.4.5, this prints out:

```
EOF: false
EOF: true
```

So, why is the behavior different here?  This subtle difference managed to confuse me enough to wonder why there is a difference.  Is there some compelling reason that EOF is triggered "early" with a call to ignore?

Comment: I don't think it should do that.  What compiler are you using?  Mine(VC10) prints false for both.

Comment: Or, maybe it should.  I'm trying to decipher this line from the definition of ignore in the standard "Characters are extracted until any of the following occurs: ... `traits::eq_int_type(traits::to_int_type(c), delim)` for the next available input character c (in which case c is extracted)."  That sounds like it's doing a look-ahead by 1, I'm not sure though.

Comment: This is a bug, reproducible in [GCC 4.5.1](http://www.ideone.com/Vuzfx), [GCC 4.3.1](http://www.ideone.com/PkZ75) and [GCC 4.1.2](http://codepad.org/bjo4jhtY). Can't find [any relevant existing entry in GCC bugzilla](http://tinyurl.com/6xjdem7).

Answer (score 2):

`eof()` should only return true if you have already attempted to read past the end. In neither case should it be true. This may be a bug in your implementation.

Comment: You seem to be right, according to the C++ standard.  But this seems to be a widespread bug: http://codepad.org/bjo4jhtY

Answer (score 2):

I'm going to go out on a limb here and answer my own question:  it really looks like this is a bug in GCC.

The standard reads in 27.6.1.3 paragraph 23:

> [istream::ignore] behaves as an
>   **unformatted input function** (as
>   described in 27.6.1.3, paragraph 1). 
>   After constructing a sentry object,
>   extracts characters and discards them.
>   Characters are extracted until any of
>   the following occurs:
>
> - if n != numeric_limits::max()
>     (18.2.1), n characters are extracted
> - end-of-file occurs on the input sequence (in which case the function
>     calls setstate(eofbit), which may
>     throw ios_base::failure(27.4.4.3));
> - c == delim for the next available input character c (in which case c is
>     extracted). Note: The last condition
>     will never occur if delim ==
>     traits::eof()

My (somewhat tentative) interpretation is that GCC is wrong here, because of the bold parts above.  Ignore should behave as an *unformatted input function*, (like `read()`), which means that end-of-file should only occur on the input sequence if there is an attempt to extract additional bytes *after* the last byte in the stream has been extracted.

I'll submit a bug report if I find that enough people agree with this answer.

Comment: Regarding "But it appears to be a widespread bug", codepad uses GCC also.

Comment: I tried it on an old version of GCC, (version 3.6), and it prints out `false false`

Answer (score 0):

The consensus seemed to be that this was a legitimate bug in gcc.  Since I saw no indication a bug report had been filed, I'm doing so now.  The report can be viewed at:

http://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=51651